# Convert javascript array to HTML and append to table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have this javascript/array...

```
var prodPrice = { // quantity prices, lowest no. is min qty
   "11580294ce6c41e574c7e9efe063bf01": {
      minqty: 1,
      name: "Diamond Pillar",
      imageURL: "",
      bigImageURL: "",
      prices: [
         {price: 79.96, qty: 1},
         {price: 75.96, qty: 10},
         {price: 72.16, qty: 25},
         {price: 70.36, qty: 50},
         {price: 68.60, qty: 100}
      ]
   },
   "49f398d1cce9093be484eb5afa1c5ed9": {
      minqty: 1,
      name: "Diamond Pillar",
      imageURL: "",
      bigImageURL: "",
      prices: [
         {price: 119.96, qty: 1},
         {price: 113.96, qty: 10},
         {price: 108.26, qty: 25},
         {price: 105.56, qty: 50},
         {price: 102.92, qty: 100}
      ]
   }
}
```

I would like the grab the prices from the above array and either append them as extra rows on to another table OR create a brand new table like so...

```
                1       10      25       50       100
Diamond Pillar  79.96   75.96   72.16    70.36    68.60
Diamond Pillar  119.96  113.96  108.26   105.56   102.92
```

I hope this makes sense - thanks as always for any help

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Do it so! Or do you have any problems? Any specific question about your code?

Comment: for the record, that's not really an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try my quick solution(if you want you can refactor my code):

```
var keys = Object.keys(prodPrice);

(function () {
   var body = document.body,
      tbl = document.createElement("table"),
      firstTableRow = tbl.insertRow(0);
   firstTableRow.insertCell(-1);
   for (key in keys) {
      if (undefined !== prodPrice[keys[key]].prices) {
         var i = 0,
            tr = tbl.insertRow(1),
            priceLen = prodPrice[keys[key]].prices.length;
         tr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(prodPrice[keys[key]].name));
         if(0 < priceLen) {
            for (i = 0; i < priceLen; i++) {
               if(undefined !== prodPrice[keys[key]].prices[i].price) {
                  if (0 == key) {
                     firstTableRow.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(prodPrice[keys[key]].prices[i].qty));
                  }
                  tr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(prodPrice[keys[key]].prices[i].price));
               }
            }
         }
      }
      body.appendChild(tbl);
   }
})();
```

You can try my code here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsk3q/).

Also you must read more about javaScript objects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Answer (score 0):

- create a table with the default heading row (the one showing 1, 10, 25, etc...)
- loop through all the products
- for each one create a new table row
- for each component create a table cell within that row and fill it with the appropriate data

Answer (score 0):

You can try this my quick solution(if you want you can refactor my code):

```
var keys = Object.keys(prodPrice);

(function () {
   var body = document.body,
      tbl = document.createElement("table"),
      firstTableRow = tbl.insertRow(0);
   firstTableRow.insertCell(-1);
   for (key in keys) {
      if (undefined !== prodPrice[keys[key]].prices) {
         var i = 0,
            tr = tbl.insertRow(1),
            priceLen = prodPrice[keys[key]].prices.length;
         tr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(prodPrice[keys[key]].name));
         if(0 < priceLen) {
            for (i = 0; i < priceLen; i++) {
               if(undefined !== prodPrice[keys[key]].prices[i].price) {
                  if (0 == key) {
                     firstTableRow.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(prodPrice[keys[key]].prices[i].qty));
                  }
                  tr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(prodPrice[keys[key]].prices[i].price));
               }
            }
         }
      }
      body.appendChild(tbl);
   }
})();
```

You can try my code here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsk3q/)
If you want add style for table:

```
 tbl.style.width = "100%";
 tbl.style.border = "1px solid black";
```